How do I pass chromedriver file path with seleniumbase
I am using seleniumbase to open a url in chrome browser. My python project is located in shared folder and it will be executed on a virtual machine. I got the following error when I want to execute the chromedriver.exe from my virtual environment, which is located on the shared folder I mentioned:

Service \[path to my shared
folder].venv\Lib\site-packages\seleniumbase\drivers/chromedriver.exe
unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 1

I found chromedriver can be only executed on local folder in the virtual machine. Therefore, I found a workaround to solve this issue by using a local folder path in the C drive of my virtual machine like "C:/driver/chromedriver.exe". Now my challenge is how do I pass this path with selenium base to use this executable?. This is my current code:
from seleniumbase import Driver as sbDriver

def get_with_selenium(url: str,
                      headless: bool, 
                      user_agents: list,
) -> dict:
       
    user_agent = random.choice(user_agents['agents']) 
    
    # Get folder path of the Documents
    chromedriver_path = "C:/driver/chromedriver.exe"
    driver = sbDriver(
                          headless=headless,
                          agent=user_agent,
                          binary_location=chromedriver_path
                          )
    driver.get(url)
    driver.maximize_window()
    ... 

        

However, after executing this code I got the following warning because the provided path was invalid and it continues to use the default path to execute chromedriver:
Warning: The Chromium binary specified is NOT valid!
Expecting "chromedriver.exe" to be found in ['chrome.exe', 'chromium.exe', 'brave.exe', 'opera.exe
'] for the browser / OS!
(Will use default settings...)

